# Import Selected Columns to Excel from Access Table using VBA

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to import selected data from an access table. This table has 4 columns and I want only want columns 2 and 3. In Excel and want them listed in the order: column 3, column 2 (reverse to how they are in Access). Additionally I want to select rows (From Access table) based on a date referenced in the Excel Spread sheet (which I refer to as RpDate in the code). In Access, "Date" is the first column. I need some help please. Thanks.

```
Sub ADOImportFromAccessTable()
Dim DBFullName As String
Dim TableName As String
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim RpDate As Range

DBFullName = "C:\Documents\Database.mdb"
TableName = "DataTable"
TargetRange = Range("C5")
RpDate = Range("B2").Value

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, intColIndex As Integer
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    ' open the database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & _
        "C:\Documents\Database.mdb" & ";"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        ' open the recordset
        .Open TableName, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
        ' all records
        .Open "SELECT * FROM " & TableName & _
            " WHERE [Date] = RpDate, cn, , , adCmdText"
        ' filter rows based on date
        rs.Open , TargetRange

    End With
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? Where do you have trouble? Any error?

Comment: Also, give us the names of the columns. The solution, I guess, will be like `SELECT Column2, Column3 FROM table WHERE [Date] = RpDate ORDER BY Column3, Column2`

Comment: The column names (in order) are: Date, Time, Tank, Comments. I only want the Tank and Time columns imported into Excel, in the order Tank, Time.

Comment: I am also getting a Compile error: Sub or Function not defined. It is referring to "WHERE"                                              
        

.Open TableName, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
        
        .Open "SELECT Time, Tank * FROM " & TableName
             WHERE [Date] = "RpDate", "ORDERBY Tank, Time, cn, , , adCmdText"
        
        rs.Open , TargetRange

Comment: you need to close quotes right `ORDERBY Tank, Time", cn, , , adCmdText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub ADOImportFromAccessTable()
Dim DBFullName As String
Dim TableName As String
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim RpDate As Range

DBFullName = "C:\Documents\Database.mdb"
TableName = "DataTable"
Set TargetRange = Range("C5")
RpDate = Range("B2").Value

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, intColIndex As Integer
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    ' open the database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & _
        "C:\Documents\Database.mdb" & ";"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        ' open the recordset
        .Open TableName, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
        ' all records
        .Open "SELECT Time, Tank  FROM " & TableName & " WHERE [Date] = " & RpDate & " ORDER BY Tank, Time", cn, , , adCmdText
        ' filter rows based on date            

    End With
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

This isn't prof to SQL injection, but is a start

Comment: I am getting a Run-time error: Object variable or With block variable not set. It is at 

TargetRange = Range("C5")

Comment: I edited the code, but the error was there before and you didn't mention it, its not related to your question. Just add a `Set` before assigning an object

Comment: Thanks. I am getting another Run-time error '3705': Ooperation is not allowed when the object is open.

With rs
        
        .Open TableName, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
    
.Open "SELECT Time, Tank  FROM " & TableName & " WHERE [Date] = " & RpDate & " ORDER BY Tank, Time", cn, , , adCmdText
        
       'The error is in the above line

 rs.Open , TargetRange

    End With

Comment: I'm trying to figure how to deal with that last error. I am sure it will need some tuning even after that.

Comment: I have been unable to fix this error, some more help please @Horaciux

Comment: @Kish I can't help any longer, I helped with SQL part, I can't test your code. Please accept this partial answer and ask a new one for more people to see it. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Kish please accept this answer by clicking on the green mark. That is how you earn point an privileges, and so am I. look:  stackoverflow.com/tour